# Calculus proof for volume of a general pyramid

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, 3d, volume, solid-geometry

**Is the proof on the volume of a generalzing the volume of a [square pyramid](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-volume-of-a-pyramid-using-integrals) correct**

Introduce a $z$ axis perpendicular to the base, and positive in the downward direction, with the origin at the tip of the pyramid.

Let the area of the base of the pyramid be $B$.
For $0<z<h$, a cross section parallel to the base of the pyramid is similar to the base. Since the side lengths are $\propto z$, the area are $\propto  z^2$.

$$\text{Area of Cross Section at a depth of z = } A(z) = B\times\frac{z^2}{h^2}$$

Now, using the standard Calculus formula for volume of a solid:
$$\text{Volume}
=\int_{0}^{h}{A(z)}dz
=\int_{0}^{h}{\left(B\times\frac{z^2}{h^2}\right)}dz
=\frac{B}{h^2}\int_{0}^{h}{z^2}dz
=\frac{B}{h^2}\times \frac{h^3}{3}
=\frac{Bh}{3}
$$

which is the standard formula for volume of a pyramid

Comment: Compare [this answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100729/139123). They wrote $H$ where you wrote $h$ and they wrote $h$ where you wrote $z$. The one thing that answer has that is not so clear from your proof is where the denominator $h^2$ comes from.

Comment: @DavidK That is very useful. I edited it to attempt to improve the clarity. Does the rest of it look ok?

Comment: You hold $h$ constant while the parallel cross sections vary in size. (I'm almost sorry that I linked to a question that uses $h$ differently.) I think you mean to say the side lengths are proportional to $z$ and the areas proportional to $z^2.$ That means the area is $kz^2$ for some constant of proportionality $k.$ In particular, $k = B/h^2$ ... why? Because you need something that gives the result $B$ for the particular cross section at $z=h$, which happens also to be the base of the entire pyramid.

Comment: @DavidK You are correct. I did not pay attention when writing (and that is a cardinal error). It is indeed proportional to z and z^2, respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Volume of Pyramid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100715/volume-of-pyramid)

Comment: My question was to verify my proof....