# Generalizing the "The Volume of a Cone is a Third that of its Bounding Cylinder" fact

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry

The ancient result is that a right-circular cone of height $h$ and base-radius $r$ will have volume $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2h$, which is $1/3$ the volume of the cylinder with same base and height. And the same is true if you start with a square-based pyramid: it's volume will be $1/3$ the volume of the rectangular prism that it lives in. [Here's a relevant MathSE question for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/623/167197).

What is the most general statement of this fact that we currently know to be true?

Thinking of the locally two-dimensional case, I'm *pretty sure* that this fact still holds if you start with any "nice" bounded planar region, build a generalized cylinder with bases and cross-sections congruent to that region, then take any point on a base of that cylinder as the apex of your cone. And then this generalizes even further due to [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle). But is this true? And in what generality is is true? Like, what conditions must we have on our base region? Furthermore, is there a version of this in higher dimensional spaces? Is there a version of this in spaces that are not $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: given a planar shape with area S and a point in space with distance H from the plane of the planar shape, the volume of the object created from connecting the point to the contour of the planar shape is given by SH/3. Is this general enough to your taste?:)

Comment: I believe that this can be extended to higher spaces by having a proper n-1 dimension object and a point in the n space and the n dimension created volume will be by creating the n dimension from connecting the point to the "surface" of the n-1 dimension object divided by n. It is true for 2D and 3D.

Comment: @Moti nah, way more general. Like, are we sure that what happens in your second comment actually happens in higher dimensions? Also, what are we qualifying as a "planar shape?" What if the boundary of the shape is not [rectifiable](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rectifiable_curve)? I'm pretty sure that's fine. But is there any way that you *can* mess with the "shape," to where this will no longer hold true?

Comment: The only requirement from the n-1 dimension shape that it is defined by n-2 elements and that its n-1 volume is well defined. for example - 1, 2, and 3 dimension - the n-2 line has to be a straight line, well defined in as 1 dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $n$-dimensional prism still has volume formula
$$V_n=V_{n-1}\cdot h$$
while the $n$-dimensional pyramid has volume formula
$$V_n=\frac1n\cdot V_{n-1}\cdot h$$
where $V_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of the base facet and $h$ is the orthogonal height.

For $n=1$ you'd simply use $V_0=1$ and you see that $V_1=h$ in either formula. The case $n=2$ also is easy by planar geometry, and $n=3$ was the starting point of your question $-$ and as such admitted to be correct either.

A visualization of the idea on how this generalizes for instance is outlined [here](http://physicsinsights.org/pyramids-1.html), by dissecting the according $n$-dimensional hypercube by its body diagonal into $n$ copies of a pyramid on a $(n-1)$-dimensional hypercube (q.e. a facet of the former).

--- rk

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that the $1/3$ wouldn't stick around in higher dimensions. You wouldn't happen to know if you can use the case of the $n$-dimensional pyramid as a basis for answering this question for different bases, would you? Like suppose you start with a generalized cylinder with $n$-dimensional base region (facet?) $R$. Can you show that the generalized cone of facet $R$ will have hyper-volume $1/(n+1)$ that of the generalized cylinder by chopping up $R$ into $n$-cubes, looking at the volumes of these pyramids, then taking a limit as the number of $n$-cubes approaches infinity?

Comment: @MikePierce Chopping into little cubes is hard. What you want is the $n$-dimensional analog of Cavalieri's principle, as your questions suggests. That's where the $1/n$ comes from. It starts with the formula for the area of a triangle when $n=2$.