# Volume of polygon-based pyramid

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, area, volume

I read in a book a few months ago that the volume of a (solid) pyramid with a base that is ANY polygon (I'm not sure if it mentioned it being regular or not) is equal to
$$\frac{1}{3}\times A\times h$$
where $A$ is the area of the base (i.e. of the polygon) and $h$ is the height of the pyramid.

This seems to be true in many cases, such as when the base is a square, a triangle and when the base is a circle (ie the pyramid becomes a cone).

My question is, how can we prove this? I simply have no idea.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Similar, but not exactly your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623/why-is-the-volume-of-a-cone-one-third-of-the-volume-of-a-cylinder. Note the comment by Jamie Banks outlining a proof via calculus, which applies to any arbitrary base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any polygon can be decomposed into triangles, giving $A = A_1 + \cdots + A_n$.

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
V &= V_1 + \cdots + V_n\\
&=\frac13A_1h + \cdots + \frac13A_nh\\
&=\frac13(A_1 + \cdots + A_n)h\\
&=\frac13Ah.
\end{align}$$

---

For the base case, you can decompose a prism like so. To see that the three pyramids have the same volume, note that the left and middle pyramids share a blue base and have the same height; similarly, the middle and right pyramids share a red base and have the same height.

[image]

Comment: I think you also have to prove that the volume of a triangular pyramid is $\frac{1}3Ah$ though. The OP wants the valid proof for all kinds of polygon bases including triangle.

Comment: @Student1058 Sure: in that case, simply decompose a triangular prism into pyramids. No integration is required.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it's beautiful in its simplicity! I'm not quite sure how you'd split a triangular prism into pyramids; would you mind elaborating please?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Glad to help. I drew a picture illustrating the decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for the illustration, I really appreciate it. So how exactly does that show that the volume of a triangular pyramid is $\frac{1}{3}Ah$?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Given that the three pyramids all have the same volume, it follows that they each have a volume equal to a third of that of the prism, which is $Ah$. This is very similar to calculating the area of a triangle: cut a rectangle in a half along the diagonal, and, observing that the two resulting triangles have the same area, they must each be $\frac12wh$.

Comment: Ah I see it now-thanks so much once again! Your diagram is really nice by the way; how did you make it?

Comment: @A-levelStudent You're welcome! I did it in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), which is a freeware vector graphics program.

Answer (score 2):

For the most general case in which the base doesn't even need to be a polygon, it is an application of [Cavalieri's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle).  Imagine a pyramid with a blob-shaped base and a square pyramid next to it with the same height and whose base has the same area as that of the first pyramid.  Since any level cross-section of the two pyramids would have to have the same area, the volumes must also be equal.

There is a marvelous image showing that the area of a square pyramid whose height is equal to its base size and whose apex is above one corner of the base is 1/3 the volume of a unit cube.  Long story short, you can construct three of those pyramids and see that they can be fit together to form a unit cube.  From there, the only remaining step is to convince yourself that the volume of a pyramid whose base is a unit square is directly proportional to the height of the pyramid.  At that point, you've proved it from a unit square pyramid with unit height to a unit square pyramid of arbitrary height to an arbitrary base and arbitrary height.

Comment: Is Cavalieri's Principle the idea explained in the first paragraph?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Yeah, I should have tossed in a link to the Wikipedia page.  Give me a minute to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting!