# How to sample uniformly from an $\epsilon$ ball?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, functional-analysis, statistics, probability-theory

Given a real rectangular matrix $X$, I would like to uniformly sample from the set of real rectangular matrices $\mathbb{M}$ that satisfy $||X-S||\leq \epsilon, \forall S\in\mathbb{M}$ and for a fixed real, scalar radius $\epsilon$.

Now procedurally/algorithmically, how can I obtain a matrix $\hat{S}$ (sample) by such a 'uniform sampling' within the specified radius? The key is that the sampling should be uniform when obtaining an instance $\hat{S}$. What would be the necessary steps to be taken to be able to do this?

The fact that the set $\mathbb{M}$ seems very large is why the notion of sampling really confuses me to be able to assign a probability law although the $\epsilon$ does constraint the set to an extent.

The following is what I am trying to do, i.e get a sample of the type $X_k$ as shown in the  screenshots attached below:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can do a uniform sample in X and discard those that not respect your restriction.

Comment: I think you should make precise what you mean by "uniform sampling", as I can think of a few possible interpretations.

Comment: what norm are you using ?

Comment: @mike Euclidean Norm

Comment: @halms: That can't be what you mean.  There are infinitely many such matrices; if they are all equally likely, that just says each one has probability zero.

Comment: @NateEldredge I meant that $\forall S \in \mathbb{M}$ satisfying the $\epsilon$ constraint, each matrix has a equal probability of being sampled in the sampling procedure. I see you having a deep probabilistic background, leading to different view points, but this is what i meant. Also for the case with column matrices as well, I would need a procedure/algorithm. Now, after you put forth this question, I thought a bit and was wondering about a special cases as well:    i) The case when the set $\mathbb{M}$ has more structural properties like lying on the Steifel or Grassman manifolds

Comment: @NateEldredge I attached a picture in the question, talking about a sample of this sort. I think this will help you understand it better, in case I might have missed something although I agree with what you are saying. Please look at this screenshots in terms of the sample $X_k$ as mentioned over there. There is also a set of points of differentiability $D$ of a chosen function $f(.)$ that is also considered.

Comment: this is no different from drawing a point uniformly from the unit ball in $\mathbb R^{m = n^2}$.  Get one uniform on the sphere by sampling i.i.d. normals and  normalizing to be 1.  Then multiply by  something that gives right radius.

Comment: @mike can you post it as an answer? Also, were you suggesting it with the view point of a column vector or for matrices, in terms of the normalization of an i.i.d normal sample followed by multiplying with the radius?

Comment: I think if you are using euclidean norm it doesn't make any difference, the matrices are the same as $\mathbf R^{N^2}$.

Comment: @Mike I tried your answer and after the multiplication with the radius, the sphere is centered around zero, I guess the sphere has to also be translated to the required center which would be the vectorized matrix X

Comment: @NateEldredge Your answer over here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability  helps me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can draw uniformly a matrix on the space $Q = \{ S: \forall (i,j), \vert S_{i,j} - X_{i,j} \vert \leq \epsilon \} \subset \mathbb M$ and then keep only the matrices in $\mathbb M$. Although, I have the feeling that the probability of the event $ (S \in \mathbb M) \vert (S \in Q)$ is very small when the size of the $X$ is big...

Comment: This is like Rejection sampling, and you are right, the expected number of trials required would grow to be very large/intractable