# Uniform distribution on the surface of unit sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It is known that given $X=(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ iid $\sim N(0,1)$, then $X/\sqrt{X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2}$ is uniformly distributed on the surface of unit sphere.

Intuitively, I know that that's because the probability of $X/\sqrt{X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2}$ belonging to any region with the same area on the surface should be the same. But how can I prove it mathematically?

Comment: See the references in                                           [the article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

Comment: @user64494 i saw that page before but the references there only mentioned the method, not a detailed proof.

Comment: Have you tried to use spherical coordinates?

Comment: [The proof in less than 600 characters](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe#comment13055_7984).

Comment: @cardinal Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a very simple method that you could consider : it amounts to generate first a uniform distribution of oints on the (truncated) cylinder the circumscribed to the unit sphere along its equator with total height 2 ; see the last answer by leonbloy in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87230)

Answer (score 15):

Suppose $X=(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ iid and $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$, then $X \sim N(0, I_n)$, where $N(0, I_n)$ is [the multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with zero-mean and identity covariance matrix. From that it follows, that if $O$ is an orthogonal matrix, that $OX$ is identically distributed with $X$. From that it follows, that $Y = \frac{X}{||X||_2}$ is identically distributed with $\frac{OX}{||OX||_2} = \frac{OX}{||X||_2}$. From that we can conclude, that $Y$ is invariant under rotations and belongs to the unit sphere. There is only one probability distribution, that satisfies both those conditions at the same time: that is the uniform distribution on the unit sphere.

Comment: Could you explain why there is only one distribution that satisfies invariance under rotations and belonging to the unit sphere?  I asked a question about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403186/a-random-vector-satisfying-invariance-under-rotation-and-belonging-to-the-unit-s