# Showing $\|Y\|_2$ and $\frac{Y}{\|Y\|_2}$ are independent where $Y\sim N(0,\mathbb{1}_N)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Suppose $Y\sim N(0,\mathbb{1}_N)$. Now let us write 
$$Y=r\vec{Y},$$

where $r:=\|Y\|_2$ and $\vec{Y}:=Y/\|Y\|_2$. I am trying to show that $r$ and $\vec{Y}$ are independent random variables.

I think it's not that I can't do it, it is more I am confused about what has to be done.

**My understanding:**
So I understand that I have to show that their respective probabilities don't depend on each other, but how do I know what their probabilities are? Suppose I could parameterise their probabilities, how would I be able to check these parameterisations of probabilities will suffice?

any tips are hints will be appreciated!

EDIT:

For $Y$ I have the following pdf:

$$f_Y(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}e^{-\|x\|_2^2/2}=\prod_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}e^{-x^2_i/2}$$

EDIT (2):

Can it also be shown that $\vec{Y}$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere $S^{N-1}$?

EDIT (3):

I've shown using polar coordinates that:

$$\int{}f_Y(x)dx=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi{\dddot{}}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\infty{e^{\frac{1}{2}r^{n-1}}}\sin^{n-3}(\varphi_2)...\sin(\varphi_{n-2})drd\varphi_1...d\varphi_{n-1}$$.

Comment: Can you give the density for $Y$? Can you separate out a part based on $r$ or $r^2$ leaving a part related to $\vec{Y}$?

Comment: I have added an edit. So are you suggesting I have to do something like: $f_Y(x)=f_r(x)f_\vec{Y}(x)$?

Comment: You should be able to separate out a density for $r \sim \mathcal N(0,N)$ leaving a constant density for $\vec{Y}$

Comment: One hitch is that $\ \vec{Y}\ $ doesn't actually have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\ \mathbb{R}^N\ $ (although it does, of course, have a constant density with respect to *area* on $\ S^N\ $).

Comment: So im assuming the idea here is that for any subset of an 
N
 sphere, it intersects a subset of the 1−
x
1
−
a
x
i
s
only once. So integrating a single point is 0 because it has zero lebesgue measure? hence this integral holds??

Comment: The integrand in your final integral is not correct.  The transformation from spherical to cartesian coordinates is given by$$
x_i=\cases{r\cos\phi_1&if $\ i=1\ $,\\
r\cos\phi_i\prod_\limits{j=1}^{i-1}\sin\phi_j&for $\ 2\le i\le n-1\ $\\ r\prod_\limits{j=1}^{n-1}\sin\phi_j& if $\ i=n\ $.}$$
Thus, $\ e^{-\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\ $ not $\ e^{-\frac{1}{2} r^{n-1}}\ $.

Comment: Also, the volume element in spherical coordinates is
$$
r^{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}\sin^{n-i-1}\phi_i\,drd\phi_1d\phi_2\dots d\phi_{n-1}\ .
$$
So your identity should read
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_Y(x)dx=\\
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{n}{2}}\int_0^\pi\dots\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty r^{n-1}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}drd\phi_1\dots d\phi_{n-1}\ ,
$$
with the integral over $\ \phi_1\ $ (not that over $\ \phi_{n-1}\ $) having the range $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/700629/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444700/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what the joint probability distribution of $\ \left(r, \vec{Y}\right)\ $ is, because $\ r\ $ and $\ \vec{Y}\ $ are both functions of $\ Y\ $, and you're told that $\ Y=\left(Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_N\right)\ $ is a vector of independent standard normal variates.  That is,
$$
P\left(Y\in A\right)=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^\frac{N}{2}}\int_Ae^{-\frac{\|y\|_2^2}{2}}dy
$$
for any measurable $\ A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N\ $.  What  you have to do is show that if $\ B_1\ $ and $\ B_2\ $ are any measurable subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}_+\ $ and $\  S^{N-1}\ $ (i.e. the [unit $(N-1)$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)) respectively, and $\ A_1=\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}^N\right|\,\|y\|_2\in B_1\left.\right\}, $$A_2=$$\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}^N\right|\left.\frac{y}{\|y\|_2}\in B_2\right\}\ $, then $\ P\left(Y\in A_1\cap A_2\right)=$$P\left(Y\in A_1\right)\times$$P\left(Y\in A_2\right)\ $. All the probabilities in this identity can be evaluated by using the above identity for $\ P\left(Y\in A\right)\ $.

In spherical coordinates, the above integral becomes
\begin{align}
P&\left(Y\in A\right)=\\
&\hspace{-0.5em}\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^\frac{N}{2}}\int_{g_S(A)}r^{N-1}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}\sin^{N-i-1}\phi_i\,drd\phi_1d\phi_2\dots d\phi_{N-1}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ g_s:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow[0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi)\times[0,
\pi)^{N-2}\ $ is the map from cartesian to polar coordibares, and if $ A=A_1\cap A_2\ $, it becomes
\begin{align}
P\left(Y\in A_1\cap A_2\right)&=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^\frac{N}{2}}\int_{B_1}r^{N-1}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}dr\,\times\\
&\int_{\,\\\hspace{-1em}\vec{u}_\phi\in B_2} \prod_{i=1}^{N-2}\sin^{N-i-1}\phi_i\,d\phi_1d\phi_2\dots d\phi_{N-1}\ ,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\vec{u}_\phi&=\\
&\left(\cos\phi_1, \cos\phi_2\sin\phi_1,\dots, \cos\phi_{n-1}\prod_\limits{i=1}^{n-2}\sin\phi_i, \prod_\limits{i=1}^{n-1}\sin\phi_i\right)\ .
\end{align}
Putting $\ B_2=S^{N-1}\ $ (and hence $\ A_2=\mathbb{R}^N\ $) gives
\begin{align}
P\left(Y\in A_1\right)&=P\left(\|Y\|_2\in B_1\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{N}{2}-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)}\int_{B_1} r^{N-1}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}dr\ ,
\end{align}
and putting $\ B_1=\mathbb{R}_+\ $ (and hence $\ A_1=\mathbb{R}^N\ $) gives
\begin{align}
P\left(Y\in A_2\right)&=P\left(\vec{Y}\in B_2\right)\\
&\hspace{-2em}= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{N}{2}+1\right)}{N\pi^\frac{N}{2}}\int_{\,\\\hspace{-1em}\vec{u}_\phi\in B_2} \prod_{i=1}^{N-2}\sin^{N-i-1}\phi_i\,d\phi_1d\phi_2\dots d\phi_{N-1}\ .
\end{align}
Now multiplying the expressions for $\ P\left(Y\in A_1\right)\ $ and $\ P\left(Y\in A_2\right)\ $ together, and using the identity $\ \Gamma(z+1)=$$z\Gamma(z)\ $, you find that the product is identical to the expression for $\ P\left(Y\in A_1\cap A_2\right) \ $.

Comment: So im assuming the idea here is that for any subset of an $N$ sphere, it intersects a subset of the $x_1-axis$ only once. So integrating a single point is 0 because it has zero lebesgue measure? hence this integral holds??

Comment: No. I've no idea why you think that any of those statements follow from what I wrote.  The unit $N$-sphere intersect the $\ x_1$-axis *twice*,  at $\ (-1,0,\dots,0)\ $ and $\ (1,0,\dots,0)\ $, but I don't believe that fact bears any relevance to the question at hand.  Neither does the fact that the integral over a singleton is zero, except insofar as singletons are among the sets for which the identity $\ P\left(A_1\cap A_2\right)= P\left(A_1\right)\times P\left(A_2\right)\ $ must hold.

Comment: Ok, I think im confused as to how you explicitly split the integral into the product of integrals over the two subsets?

Comment: I'd do it by changing variables in the integral from cartesian to [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

Comment: What would $A_1\cap{}A_2$ look like in spherical coordinates then?

Comment: Is it possible you could add to your solution to show me how? I would be very appreciative.

Comment: is it ok to write $dy$ as $dy_1dy_2...dy_N$?

Comment: Yes, $\ dy\ $ is just shorthand for $\ dy_1dy_2\dots dy_N\ $.

Comment: I understand that r doesn't change w.r.t to any of the $\varphi_i$ so I can pull it out. And I understand that now I have a product of two integrals, one is using spherical coordinates and since $\vec{Y}$ is uniformly distributed over the sphere this is fine. However, how can I show that the integral w.r.t r is the same pdf for $r=\|Y\|_2$?

Comment: How do you get rid of the $r^{n-1}$ term?