# Normalized vector of Gaussian variables is uniformly distributed on the sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I have seen in various places the following claim:

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $\cdots$, $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and be independent. Then, the vector
$$
X = \left(\frac{X_1}{Z}, \frac{X_2}{Z}, \cdots, \frac{X_n}{Z}\right)
$$
is a uniform random vector on $S^{n-1}$, where $Z = \sqrt{X_1^2 + \cdots + X_n^2}$.

Many sources claimed this fact follows easily from the orthogonal-invariance of the normal distribution, but somehow I couldn't construct a rigorous proof. (one such "sketch" can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe#comment13055_7984)).

How to prove this rigorously?

**Edit:**

It has been brought to my attention that this question was already asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444700/uniform-distribution-on-the-surface-of-unit-sphere).  However, I find the answer there to be incomplete-it shows that $X$ is orthogonally-invariant, but does not explicitly explains why that implies it is uniform. Therefore I think there is value in keeping this copy as well, as I guess we cannot transfer the answer.

In my question, I explicitly asked for a complete rigorous proof-and I find the answer there to be incomplete.

Comment: Is there some papers which explain this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The two word answer is "polar coordinates".

In more detail, let $f:S^{n-1}\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Then
$$
\eqalign{
\Bbb E[f(X)]
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x_1/z,\ldots,x_n/z)(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-z^2/2}\,dx_1\cdots dx_n\cr
&=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_0^\infty\left[\int_{S^{n-1}} f(u)\,\sigma_{n-1}(du)\right]e^{-r^2/2}r^{n-1}\,dr\cr
&=c_n\int_{S^{n-1}} f(u)\,\sigma_{n-1}(du).\cr
}
$$
Here $\sigma_{n-1}$ is the "surface area" measure on the sphere $S^{n-1}$  and $$
c_n=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}r^{n-1}\,dr = \pi^{-n/2}2^{-1}\Gamma(n/2).
$$
 (Thus $2\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(n/2)$ is the surface area of $S^{n-1}$.)

Comment: Thanks! one question though; why the fact the expectation (after composing with real functions) behaves identically to uniform distribution implies the distribution was indeed uniform? (I guess I am asking why the information on the first moment determines the distribution).

Comment: Because $f$ is an *arbitrary* continuous function.   By approximating the indicator of a closed set $F\subset S^{n-1}$ by continuous functions you can show that $\Bbb P[X\in F]$ coincides with the probability accorded $F$ by the uniform distribution on $S^{n-1}$. Once you have this for closed sets it follows automatically for Borel sets.

Comment: very beautiful and elegant proof

Comment: Does this theorem hold for any other distributions as well? ie. Not just gaussian?