# Explicit calculation of the arccos-1-kernel

Tags: uniform-distribution, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have given the following problem from the draft [book of Francis Bach](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Efbach/ltfp_book.pdf):
"For $(w,b/R)$ uniform on the sphere and for the ReLU activation, compute the associated kernel as a function of the cosine between the vectors $(x,R)$ and $(x^\prime,R)$.

Now what I first tried is to omit the bias in a first step and to directly compute the integral
$$ \frac{1}{V_{n-1}(R)}\int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \max(0,w^Tx ) \max(0,w^Tx^\prime) \sigma_{n-1}(dw) $$
where $V_{n-1}(R)$ denotes the surface are of the $n-1$ dimensional sphere with radius $R$. However, I got stuck quite immediately. Therefore I did some online research and found the paper of [Cho and Saul](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esaul/papers/nips09_kernel.pdf) where they compute the arccos kernel
$$2 \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \exp(-\frac{\Vert w \Vert^2}{2})  \Theta(w^T x) \Theta(w^T x^\prime)(w^Tx)^d (w^Tx^\prime)^d d w$$

where $\Theta$ denotes the Heavyside function $\Theta(z)=\frac{1}{2}(1+sign(z))$. Then I noticed that for $d=1$ we have that $\Theta(w^T x) \Theta(w^T x^\prime)(w^Tx)^d (w^Tx^\prime)^d =max(0,w^Tx ) \max(0,w^Tx^\prime)$. Furthermore I noticed how to connect the uniform distribution on the sphere with the standard normal distribution according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864519/normalized-vector-of-gaussian-variables-is-uniformly-distributed-on-the-sphere) also here on StackExchange.

Therefore I see that my problem is equivalent to computing the arccos-1-kernel. However, also here I quickly get stuck if I want to explicitly calculate the arccos-1-kernel. These are my calculations so far.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{V_{n-1}(R)}\int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \max(0,w^Tx ) \max(0,w^Tx^\prime) \sigma_{n-1}(dw) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \max\biggl(0,\frac{w^Tx}{\Vert w \Vert}\biggr) \max\biggl(0,\frac{w^Tx^\prime}{\Vert w \Vert}\biggr) \exp(-\frac{\Vert w \Vert^2}{2}) dw\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int\limits_{w:\text{ } w^Tx>0, \text{ } w^Tx^\prime>0} \frac{1}{\Vert w \Vert^2} w^Tx w^Tx^\prime \exp(-\frac{\Vert w \Vert^2}{2}) dw\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int\limits_{w:\text{ } w^Tx>0, \text{ } w^Tx^\prime>0} \frac{1}{\Vert w \Vert^2}  w^TKw \exp(-\frac{\Vert w \Vert^2}{2}) dw 
\end{align*}
where $K_{i,j}=x_ix_j^\prime$.

Now I am quite stuck on how to further calculate the integral

What I want to state is that I am not looking for a solution of how to calculate the arccos kernel for any $d$ but only for $d=1$. Also I have found some similar results online where one could use spherical harmonics which is also a kind of an overkill to my problem.

Thank you in advance and I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Just a quick comment since I also looked at https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esaul/papers/nips09_kernel.pdf today. Shouldn't it be $(w^Tx)^n$ and not $(w^Tx)^d$ ? See page 2 of the paper...