# Equivalent representation of the uniform distribution on the nonnegative part of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\cap\mathbb{R}_+^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

As is well known, the uniform distribution on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is equivalent to the normalized standard Gaussian distribution (cf. [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864519/normalized-vector-of-gaussian-variables-is-uniformly-distributed-on-the-sphere)). That is, if a random vector $\boldsymbol{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\boldsymbol{I}_n)$, then $\frac{\boldsymbol{x}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_2}$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. My question is, if there is an equivalent representation for the uniform distribution on the **nonnegative part** of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\cap\mathbb{R}_+^n$?

Comment: Can't you generate $x \sim N(0, I)$ then take absolute values, then normalize?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Wow! Yes, this is an elegant way that I have not come up with. Thank you.