# Function that sent the gaussian distribution to the uniform on the ball

Tags: probability-distributions, lipschitz-functions

How do we define a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to the Euclidean ball in such a way that, if we consider the multivariate standard Gaussian distribution $Z$, we have that the image of $Z$ is uniformly distributed on the Euclidean ball?
Moreover, I want such a function to have a bounded Lipschitz constant
I was thinking about the function that sent $Z$ to $\sqrt{n}\frac{Z}{\left\|Z\right\|}$, where $\left\|Z\right\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of $Z$, however with this choice I get the uniform distribution on the sphere $S^{n-1}$, not on the whole ball

Comment: Do you want the ball and the gaussian to have the same dimension?

Comment: Yes, the gaussian is the multidimensional standard gaussian on R^n, and the euclidean ball is defined as the set of points in R^n with euclidean norm less or equal than square root of n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function of $\left\|Z\right\|$ then , $$F'(x) = \alpha_n x^{n-1} e^{-\frac12x^2}\mathbf 1_{x > 0}.$$

Let $h : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb B^n$, $$h(z) = \frac1{\left\|z\right\|}F(\left\|z\right\|) z$$

> **Claim 1**: $h$ is Lipschitz

If $z_1, z_2\in \mathbb R^n$ such $\left\|z_2\right\| \le \left\|z_1\right\|$,

\begin{align}
\left\|h\left(z_1\right) - h\left(z_2\right)\right\| &= \left\|\frac1{\left\|z_1\right\|}F\left(z_1\right)z_1 - \frac1{\left\|z_2\right\|}F\left(z_2\right)z_2\right\|\\
&=\left\|
\frac{z_1\left\|z_2\right\|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - z_2\left\|z_1\right\|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)}{\left\|z_1\right\|\left\|z_2\right\|}
\right\|\\
&=\left\|
\frac{z_1\left\|z_2\right\|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - z_1\left\|z_2\right\|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right) + z_1\left\|z_2\right\|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right) - z_2\left\|z_1\right\|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)}{\left\|z_1\right\|\left\|z_2\right\|}
\right\|\\
&\le \left|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right| + \frac{\left|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right|}{\left\|z_1\right\|\left\|z_2\right\|}\left\|z_1 \left\|z_2\right\| - z_2\left\|z_1\right\|\right\|\\
&= \left|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right| + \frac{\left|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right|}{\left\|z_1\right\|\left\|z_2\right\|}\left\|z_1 \left\|z_2\right\| - z_2 \left\|z_2\right\| + z_2 \left\|z_2\right\| - z_2\left\|z_1\right\|\right\|\\
&\le \left|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right| + \frac{\left|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right|}{\left\|z_1\right\|\left\|z_2\right\|}\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\left\|z_1 - z_2\right\| + \left\|z_2\right\|\left|\left\|z_2\right\| - \left\|z_1\right\|\right|\right)\\
&= \left|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right| + \frac{\left|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right|}{\left\|z_1\right\|}\left(\left\|z_1 - z_2\right\| + \left|\left\|z_2\right\| - \left\|z_1\right\|\right|\right)\\
&\le \left|F\left(\left\|z_1\right\|\right) - F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right| + \frac{\left|F\left(\left\|z_2\right\|\right)\right|}{\left\|z_2\right\|}\left(\left\|z_1 - z_2\right\| + \left|\left\|z_2\right\| - \left\|z_1\right\|\right|\right)\\
&\le \sup_{x\ge 0}\left|F'(x)\right|\left|\left\|z_2\right\| - \left\|z_1\right\|\right| + \frac{\sup\limits_{x\ge 0}\left|F'(x)\right|\left\|z_2\right\|}{\left\|z_2\right\|}\left(\left\|z_1 - z_2\right\| + \left|\left\|z_2\right\| - \left\|z_1\right\|\right|\right)\\
& \le 3 \sup\limits_{x\ge 0} \left|F'(x)\right| \left\|z_1 - z_2\right\|
\end{align}

> **Claim 2** $F\left(\left\|Z\right\|\right)\sim U\left([0,1]\right)$.

*Proof*: Look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868400/468504)

> **Claim 3**: $\left\|Z\right\|$ and $\frac{Z}{\left\|Z\right\|}$ are independant.

*Proof*: Look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602287/468504).

> **Claim 4**: $h(Z) \sim U\left(\mathbb B^n\right)$

This is a direct consequence of the claims 2 and 3.

Comment: In this way we define a function such that the image of Z is the uniform on the euclidean ball of radius 1, right? To have the uniforn on the ball of radius square root of n, it is enough to consider the same function multiplied by square root of n? @Kroki

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: And it's possible to show that this function have a bounded lipschitz constant? @Kroki

Comment: You want to prove that $z \to f(z)$ is lipschitz?

Comment: Yes, since I need that the map is lipschitz for the rest of the exercise I'm doing @Kroki

Comment: It is lipschitz if $n \ge 2$

Comment: Is that enough for you? Or you want also the function to be lipschitz for $n=1$?

Comment: It's enough. How can I prove it? @Kroki

Comment: let me edit the answer to include the proof.

Comment: I have another question: in the first part of your answer, you said that F(||Z||) is uniformly distributed on (0,1). How to show this? @Kroki

Comment: I am editing my answer and including the full proof.

Comment: @Marco you can look at the answer now.

Comment: thank you!! A last question: we have that, since Z is a multidimensional standard gaussian, its component are independent so ||Z||^2 is distributed as a chi-squared distribution, so ||Z|| is distributed as the square root of a chi-squared distribution. So we can apply the claim 2 since the cumulative distribution function of such a distribution is continuous, right? @Kroki

Comment: Yes the answer to your question.

Comment: If you feel that the answer answers you question don't hesitate to upvote it or to accept it.