# Unit Vectors of a Gaussian Random Vector

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Say i have an n dimesional  Random vector $ \vec{r} $ whose components $ \ \{{x_1 ,x_2....,x_n\}} $ are iid Gaussian Random variables,
and I need to show that unit vectors $\hat{n}=\frac{\vec{r}}{|r|}$ are distributed uniformly on unit n sphere.

my approach to this problem was first by finding the joint pdf

$P(x_1,x_2,...x_n)=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2 })^n}\exp{(\Sigma_{i=1}^n x_i^2/2 \sigma^2)}$

then
I think I need to marginalize wrt the angle but don't know how to proceed with it .

Comment: Better to stratify by the radius.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniform distribution on the surface of unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444700/uniform-distribution-on-the-surface-of-unit-sphere)

Comment: @Semiclassical i edited  the mistake