# Distribution of norm-restricted normal distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I've been wondering if there is a result on normalized normal vectors. That is, if $X \sim N_d(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $N_d(\mu,\Sigma)$ is a $d$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution with mean vector $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and symmetric positive definite covariance matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, I would like to know the distribution of $W = X/\sqrt{X^\prime X}$.

This is a type of norm-restricted normal distribution, i.e., $X \sim N_d(\mu,\Sigma)I(\|X\| = 1)$, but I wonder if there are more mathematical properties available for this kind of distribution, e.g., moment-generating function, characteristic function, CDF, or PDF.

Comment: As a special case, if $\Sigma$ is isotropic, then $W$ is uniform on the sphere. I also suspect there’s a relation to the [vMF distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises–Fisher_distribution) here.

Comment: Special case discussed here and its linked posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444700/321264.