# One-point estimate to the gradient

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, optimization, estimation, gradient-descent

The question came to me when I'm reading a paper of an optimization algorithm. It is an iterative method and in each step we need to find the gradient of $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and do a gradient descent. Due to the lack of information of the function $f$, the author cited a so-called [one-point estimate to the gradient](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0408007.pdf):

$$\nabla f(x)\approx \mathbf{E}[(f(x + δu) − f(x))u]d/\delta$$
where $d$ is the dimension of $x$, $\delta$ is a small radius, $u$ is a uniformly random unit vector.

I tried to obtain this approximation in this way:
$$f(x+\delta x)-f(x)\approx \nabla f(x)^T \delta u=\delta u^T \nabla f(x)$$
Then multiply $u$ and take the expectation on both sides:
$$\mathbf{E}[(f(x + δu) − f(x))u]\approx \delta \mathbf{E}[u u^T \nabla f(x)]$$

Can we do something further? I'm not familiar with the vector or matrix expectation, but my intuition tells me it may have something to do with eigenvalues(maybe it's completely irrelevant).

I need help to understand the derivation of this formula.

Furthermore, I would appreciate very much if somebody could explain how to use this formula in practice. The author in [one-point estimate to the gradient](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0408007.pdf) was considering the case $f$ is a black-box function, i.e., we have no information of $f$ except the value of $f$ at $x$. Then I wonder if we only know the value of $f$ at $x$, how can we use the information of $f(x+\delta u)$ to estimate $\nabla f(x)$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you read Section 2 of the paper?

Comment: @ angryavian Yes, I do. It proves that $\nabla \mathbf{E}[(f(x + δu)] = \mathbf{E}[f(x + δu) u]d/\delta$ but it is not the proof for the formula in my question. I know that it is reasonable to say $f(x)$ can be approximated by $\mathbf{E}[f(x+\delta u)]$, but what is the intuition for the formula here, which is proposed before the lemma in section 2 without proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u\sim\text{Uniform}(\mathbf S^{d-1})$ where $\mathbf S^{d-1}$ denotes the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^d$, then [we know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444700/uniform-distribution-on-the-surface-of-unit-sphere) $u$ has the same distribution as $\frac{X}{\|X\|_2}$ where $X\sim\mathcal N(0,\mathbf I_d)$, which implies that $\mathbb E[u] = 0 $ and
$$\text{Var}[u] := \mathbb E\left[(u - \mathbb E[u])(u-\mathbb E[u])^T\right] = \mathbb E[uu^T]=\frac1d\mathbf I_d. \tag1$$

You may see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22764/covariance-matrix-of-uniform-spherical-distribution) for a proof of this last equality, which is essentially a consequence of the many symmetries of this distribution.

If we plug $(1)$ into your initial estimate, we find
$$\begin{align}\mathbf{E}[(f(x + δu) − f(x))u]&\approx \delta \mathbb{E}\left[u u^T \nabla f(x)\right]\\
&=\delta \mathbb{E}\left[u u^T \right]\nabla f(x)\\
&=\frac\delta d \nabla f(x)
\end{align} $$
where we used in the second line the fact that $\nabla f(x)$ is not random. The desired estimate follows from multiplying both sides by $d/\delta$.

Then you ask

> Furthermore, I would appreciate very much if somebody could explain [...] if we only know the value of $f$ at $x$, how can we use the information of $f(x+\delta u)$ to estimate $\nabla f(x)$?

The idea is that by "one point estimate of the gradient", we don't mean that the only information we have is $f(x)$, but rather that we want to build an estimator $\hat g$ of the gradient $g:=\nabla f(x)$ *which requires only one evaluation of $f$ to be computed* (because $f$ is a blackbox function which is costly to evaluate many times). The above discussion tells us that such an estimator $\hat g$ is given by
$$\hat g := \frac d\delta \cdot f(x+\delta u)u $$
where $u$ is one realization of the uniform distribution on the sphere. We see that $\hat g$ satisfies our requirements as it only requires to evaluate $f$ at $(x+\delta u)$ one time and it satisfies $\mathbb E[\hat g]=g$.