# Algorithm to generate an uniform distribution of points in the volume of an hypersphere/on the surface of an hypersphere.

Tags: geometry, algorithms, random, spherical-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

I am searching two simple/efficient/generic algorithms to generate a uniform distribution of random points:

- in the volume of a n-dimensional hypersphere
- on the surface of a n-dimensional hypersphere

knowing the dimension $n$, the center of the hypersphere $\vec{x}$ and its radius $r$.

How to do that ?

Comment: What kind of a random number generator are you using? Can you only generate uniformly in [0,1]? Or can you generate normally distributed random numbers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aperantly](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html), for picking points on the *surface* of a hypersphere is to generate $n$ Gaussian random variables $x_1, x_2, ...x_n$, and then use the vectors:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2}} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\ x_2\\ ..\\ x_n\\ 
\end{array} \right)$$
Which will be uniformly distributed on the the surface of the hypersphere.

Comment: The Gaussian random variables should be standard normal, i.e. N(0,1). The above formula gives a random vector on the unit n-sphere. This can be generalized to the n-sphere of radius r by simply scaling the resulting vector.

Answer (score 1):

For the volume I'd say the simlest algorithm would be a standard accept-reject algorithm.

```
(1) draw a uniform random point within an n-dimensional hypercube
(2) repeat (1) if the distance exceeds $r$, otherwise done
```

if im not mistaken though, accept-rates decrease as $n$ increases, maybe there is something more efficient

**edit**
you can also find some ideas here: [Picking random points in the volume of sphere with uniform probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability?rq=1)

**edit2** thanks to @awkward for pointing out that my suggestion to draw uniformly distributed angles is not a valid method to obtain points on the surface

Comment: Welcome to Math@SE!! Do note that this is a highly unoptimized way of generating points, especially for large $n$.

Comment: the accpet-reject-method, yes. but for the surface points?

Comment: Beware! Generating uniformly distributed angles (latitude and longitude) will _not_ give you uniformly distributed points on the surface of the three-dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer for the surface of the sphere, so I'll just address the question about the interior of the $n$-ball.

For sufficiently small $n,$
the rejection method is a reasonably efficient way to get a
uniformly distributed random point in the unit ball of $n$ dimensions.

For larger $n,$ a more efficient way to get a uniform distribution within an $n$-dimensional ball is to first find a point uniformly distributed on the surface of an $n$-dimensional sphere,
and then take a point in the same direction from the origin but at a random distance.
Given that the ball has unit radius, a concentric smaller ball of radius $x$ has volume $x^n$ times the volume of the unit ball, so if $X$ is the distance from the center to a randomly chosen point inside the unit ball, the probability distribution function of $X$ should be
$$ F_X(x) = \mathbb P(X \leq x) = \begin{cases}
 0    & x < 0, \\
 x^n  & 0 \leq x \leq 1, \\
 1    & x > 1.
\end{cases} $$

The probability density function of $X$ then is the derivative of the distribution (almost everywhere),
$$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
 n x^{n - 1} & 0 \leq x \leq 1, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

In order to produce a variable $X$ with such a distribution, given a variable $U$ that is uniformly distributed on $[0,1],$
note that for $0 \leq x \leq 1,$
$$
\mathbb P(X \leq x) = x^n = \mathbb P(U \leq x^n)
 = \mathbb P(U^{1/n} \leq x),
$$
so you can set $X = U^{1/n}.$

For a ball of radius $r$ around an arbitrary center, just take the unit ball, scale it to radius $r$ and translate it so its center is at the desired location.

Comment: How do you relate $x$ and $r$ in your pdf?

Comment: @Saeed Thanks for spotting that. It should have been just $x$. That typo was there for a long time.

Comment: My pleasure! Can you please explain how did you come up with the pdf function? Also, let $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p \sim N(0, I)$, then a random point on the surface is $p_s=p/||p||$, how would you use f$(x)$ to map $p_s$ inside the ball?

Comment: @Saeed I think it's a more complete answer now. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. There is a problem with scaling factor $X=U^{1/n}$ when $n$ gets larger since no matter how small $U$ is $X \rightarrow 1$ which means points will not be mapped inside the unit ball but they will accumulate near the surface. Let's say $n=256$, then, e.g., $U^{1/n}=0.000001^{(1/256)}=0.9474635$.

Comment: @Saeed For large dimensions almost all the volume of the sphere **is** near the surface. This is a correct result.

Comment: That is an interesting fact which I was not aware of that. Can you please refer me a link on which the volume of a sphere is discussed?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1648376/139123, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/604499/139123, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118098/139123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117688/discussion-between-david-k-and-saeed).