# Clarification about this question

Tags: volume, gamma-function

In the top voted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118098/why-is-volume-of-a-high-d-ball-concentrated-near-its-surface), it says

$A_n = n V_n$

But from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Relation_with_surface_area), I see

\begin{align*}
    A_n(R) &= \frac{2 \pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)} R^n
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
    V_n(R) &= \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(1 + \frac{n}{2})} R^n
\end{align*}

But writing this out, I get

\begin{align}
\frac{V_n(R)}{A_n(R)} &= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{n + 1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n + 2}{2}\right)} = O\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) 
\end{align}
which decays as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, not $\frac{1}{n}$.

In any case, this shows that $\frac{V_n(R)}{A_n(R)}$ decays with $n$, thereby showing that a thin shell near the surface contains most of the volume in a high-dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is difference in notation of A_n between wikipedia version and the answer version. $A_n$ in the answer corresponds to $A_{n-1}$ in the wikipedia. And taking that difference in consideration, you easily get the right ratio.

Comment: I see. In this case, I will just link this post to clarify any confusion other people might also have.