# PDF of uniform distribution over the hypersphere and the hyperball

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

There are some good questions and answers about picking random multivariate points over the surface of the hypersphere and the volume of the hyperball, just like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87238/207654) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/447023/207654).

However none of the answers provide probability density function (PDF) for these distributions.

The related Wolfram Mathworld articles ([this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallPointPicking.html)) also lack the PDFs.

The missing PDFs should be in the form $P(x; x_0, r)$.

where the parameters are

- $x_0$ is the location (center) of the hypersphere/hyperball
- $r$ is the radius of the hypersphere/hyperball

---

More specifically, the methods in question are the following:

**Picking a random multivariate over the hypersphere:**

If $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ are independent (iid) standard normal variates, then $x_0 + r \frac{X}{||X||_2}$ is uniformly distributed over the surface of the n-sphere (in the geometer's sense) with location $x_0$ and radius $r$.

**Picking a random multivariate over the hyperball:**

If $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ are independent (iid) standard normal variates, and $Y$ is a standard exponential ($\lambda = 1$) variate, then $x_0 + r \frac{X}{\sqrt{Y + ||X||_2^2}}$ is uniformly distributed over the volume of the n-ball with location $x_0$ and radius $r$.

Alternatively, using a variate $U$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, the expression $x_0 + r U^{1/n} \frac{X}{||X||_2}$ is also uniformly distributed over the hyperball.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure why it would be any more complicated than
$$
\mathcal{P}(\vec{x};\vec{x_0},r) = \frac{1}{V_n} \Theta(r - ||\vec{x} - \vec{x_0}||)
$$
for the interior of a hyperball, and 
$$
\mathcal{P}(\vec{x};\vec{x_0},r) = \frac{1}{S_n} \delta(||\vec{x} - \vec{x_0}|| - r)
$$
for the surface of a hypersphere.

The notation here is that

- $\Theta(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function),
- $\delta(x)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function),
- $S_n = 2 \pi^{n/2} r^{n-1} / \Gamma(n/2)$ is the surface area of an $n$-sphere, and
- $V_n = S_n r/n$ is the volume of an $n$-ball.

---

**EDIT:** to show that these have the correct normalization, we use polar coordinates centered at $\vec{x}_0$;  in other words, we define $\rho = \| \vec{x} - \vec{x}_0 \|$ and let the other $n-1$ coordinates be angular coordinates $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots$ on the $n$-sphere.  For the surface of a hypersphere, we then have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathcal{P}(\vec{x};\vec{x}_0,r) d^n x = \frac{1}{S_n} \int_0^\infty \delta(\rho - r) (\rho^{n-1} \, d\rho \, d\Omega)
$$
where $d^{n-1} \Omega$ stands for the solid angle element in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This is then equal to
$$
\frac{1}{S_n} \left[ \int_0^\infty \delta(\rho - r) \rho^{n-1} d\rho \right] \left[ \int d \Omega \right]
$$
The integral of the solid angle in $n$ dimensions is a [well-known result], while the "picking property" of the delta function means that the radial integral is equal to $r^{n-1}$;  so the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{S_n} \left[ r^{n-1} \right] \left[ \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)} \right] = 1.
$$

The proof for the interior of the hyperball proceeds similarly, except this time the integral over $\rho$ is
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \Theta(r - \rho) \rho^{n-1} \, d \rho = \int_0^r \rho^{n-1} \, d\rho = \frac{r^n}{n}. 
$$
This factor and the angular factor then cancel out with the factor of $1/V_n$.  (In the first equality above, we use the fact that $\Theta(r - \rho) = 0$ for $r > \rho$ and 1 for $r < \rho$.)

Comment: Great answer. I plotted the densities in Mathematica, and they seem right.

Comment: I guess the Dirac delta can be exchanged with any piecewise function which has a nonzero value only at $0$.

Comment: @plasmacel:  The Dirac delta "function" is not really well-defined as a function;  it has the property that the integral $$\int_a^b \delta(x) \, dx$$ is 1 if $a < 0 < b$ and zero otherwise.  Informally, it's equal to 0 everywhere except at $x = 0$, while $\delta(0)$ is infinite.  You can read more about it on the Wikipedia page linked above.

Comment: I meant that $\delta(x)$ in the formula can be changed to the piecewise function $f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x = 0 \\ 0 & otherwise\end{cases}$. So this way the probability density is $1$ instead of $\infty$ on the surface of the sphere, and of course $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @plasmacel:  If you do that, then the integral of the probability distribution over $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be zero;  but by the usual probability normalization condition it should be 1.  This will also be the case if $f(x)$ has any finite value at $x = 0$.  Intuitively, the probability density needs to be infinite at $x = 0$, since there is a non-zero probability in any arbitrarily thin spherical shell containing the hypersphere $\| \vec{x} - \vec{x}_0 \| = r$.

Comment: Could you give a good reference for this subject?

Comment: @Mamal:  I'm most familiar with the calculation for the volume of a hypersphere from statistical mechanics textbooks, but I can't think of one off the top of my head that presents a proof of it.  The results are cited, at least, in Reif's *Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics* and in Schroeder's *Introduction to Thermal Physics.*