# Uniformly Sampling from a High-Dimensional Unit Sphere

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, sampling

This Question is supposed to gather techniques on how to uniformly sample points on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ for large $d$. There are a few things to keep in mind for this problem, mainly as the dimension $d$ increases:

1. The computation of the norm of vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ becomes increasingly expensive. Hence methods relying on normalization of vectors become less efficient.
2. The volume of the $d$-ball in relation to larger sets containing the $d$-ball decreases. As a consequence, acceptance-rejection sampling methods become less efficient as we reject too many samples.

To give two examples of "naive" methods one might try, which do work well in low dimensions but not in large dimensions, consider the following:

**Normalizing a symmetric distribution:**

First, sample a random vector $X\in\mathbb R^d$ from a distribution which is invariant under symmetry transformations of $\mathbb S^{d-1}$, then normalize $X$, i.e. compute $X/\Vert X\Vert$. This normalized vector will be uniformly distributed on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$. This method suffers from Problem 1.

**Rejecting points from the unit cube:**

Sample a random vector $X$ uniformly in $[-1,1]^d$. If the random vector lies inside the $d$-ball, keep the sample, if not, discard the sample. This will generate a uniform distribution on the $d$-ball. A uniform distribution on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ can then be achieved by normalizing the samples. This acceptance-rejection method suffers from Problem 2, since as $d$ increases, fewer points in the unit cube are located in the unit $d$-ball and hence we will reject a lot of samples. (This method also suffers from Problem 1, but that's beside the point.)

**Question:**

What are sampling techniques that achieve a uniform distribution on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ but avoid Problems 1 and 2 for large $d$?

Comment: Let me understand: you want to sample from *inside* the ball, or on the surface?

Comment: The comment "The volume of the -ball in relation to larger sets containing the -ball decreases" is so vague as to be meaningless.

Comment: "The computation of the norm of vectors in $R^d$  becomes increasingly expensive" The complexity increases linearly on $d$. Is that really a problem?

Comment: @DavidK No, it does not. The solution proposed there suffers from problem 1.

Comment: @Snoop I'm sorry, i should have been more precise: I want to sample from the sphere, i.e. the boundary of the ball, not sample from the ball.

Comment: @leonbloy While it may not be a huge efficiency problem, it would still be nice to avoid such an extra computation.

Comment: You're right, it should have been clear from the problem statement that https://math.stackexchange.com/q/446959 does not answer the question. The only excuse I can offer for misunderstanding is that the cost of the norm seems so small in comparison to the rest of the problem that it's hard to keep in mind that this might somehow be regarded as a problem. For example, spherical coordinates would be an alternative to taking a norm, but seem far more expensive to work with.

Comment: It might help if, as part of the context for this question, you gave some numbers for how long it takes for your computing device to (a) generate a random floating-point number of the necessary precision (for both uniform and normal distributions); (b) add and multiply such numbers; and (c) take the square root of such numbers. Otherwise, optimizing this process seems hopelessly vague; it can send us to somewhat absurd lengths—some of which may be quite computationally expensive—just to avoid taking a square root.

Comment: @DanAsimov: Perhaps the OP means $d$-ball compared to $d$-hypercube, since presumably they don't want to spend time going through points from a multivariate uniform distribution that aren't inside the ball.

Comment: If computing the norm is considered prohibitively expensive, just what were you planning on doing with these points? The only part of computing that that grows with dimension is a dot product and a scalar multiplication. If you can't afford those, you probably can't afford to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dan Asimov that sampling a $d$-dimension standard normal and then renormalizing is the  best, even if the original poster has ruled it out *a priori*.

Here is a different method which produces the coordinates $x_i$ sequentially and never re-examines or re-calculates them.  Let $B_n$ denote the distribution of the first coordinate of a random point in $S^{n-1}$: it is a beta distribution on $[-1,1]$. (I think the $B_n$ distribution is that of $\pm \sqrt Y$ when $Y\sim\operatorname{Beta}(1,n-1)$. Special cases are: $B_3$ is uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$, and $B_1$ is uniform on $\{\pm1\}$.)  Here is the method.  Pick $x_1$ according to $B_d$. Pick $x_2$ by multiplying a $B_{d-1}$ variate by $\sqrt{1-x_1^2}$.  Pick $x_{i+1}$ by multiplying a $B_{d-i}$ variate by $\sqrt{1-(x_1^2+\cdots x_i^2)}$.  (One keeps track of the sums $x_1^2+\cdots x_i^2$ by updating with the square of the new coordinate $x_{i+1}^2$ and so on.)

Of course this is silly because of the cost of generating the $B_n$ variates and (as David K points out in a comment) extracting the square roots is surely too high.  But it does produce the desired coordinates in a "on-line" fashion, not needing to look back at old coordinates.

Comment: Plus the cost of computing all those square roots. But at least none of them is a normalization of a given vector!

Comment: While this method, as you and David point out, might not be more efficient than simply normalizing gaussians, i appreciate the answer! It is an interesting solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to pick the integer N such that 2N = d or 2N = d+1, and then to use *standard algorithms* to pick a standard normal random variable from the plane N times independently. This yields a standard normal choice in d-dimensional euclidean space, which divided by its length will be a uniformly chosen point on S^(d-1).

Comment: But "dividing by its length" is "Problem 1" the poser wants to avoid.

Comment: It is dividing *repeatedly* by the length that is expensive.  Meanwhile, the rejection method from the unit cube is far, far more expensive.  The fact is simply that one cannot compute with points in high-dimensional euclidean space without *sometimes* needing to divide by their length.

Comment: Your recipe is a special case of the original poser's "Normalizing a symmetric distribution".

Comment: This method is no different than sampling a $d$-dimensional standard normal and then normalizing, which is what i described under "normalizing a symmetric distribution".

Comment: And that is the best method.

Comment: This answer also duplicates the answer to [Algorithm to generate an uniform distribution of points in the volume of an hypersphere/on the surface of an hypersphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/446959/139123).