# Generating samples within a sphere according to a specified distribution

Tags: geometry, statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, random-variables

Let's consider a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at some point $x$ with radius $r$. I am interested in generating samples (random points) within this ball. It is well known that, according to sources such as [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability), using Gaussian random variables and normalizing them produces random points that are uniformly distributed within a sphere.

Now let's say I want to generate random points within this ball according to a specified distribution. Are there general procedures for doing this? Or, are there other known specific approaches that produce specific distributions within the ball?

Comment: Please add some of your ideas by editing the question.

Comment: It's not a homework question. I'm trying to do a simulation that I'm interested in and happened to need to do this. I was wondering if others have heard of it because I'm looking for references

Answer (score 1):

If you can generate random samples uniformly distributed within the $n$-dimensional sphere then you can generate other distributions by the [rejection sampling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

Here, I am going to describe the above mentioned method if the $n$-dimensional density, $f$ exists and is bounded by, say, $B$ inside the sphere. (It is zero outside the same.)

Now, let your uniformly distributed samples denoted by $\{\vec X_n\}$. Take independent random numbers, $\{Y_n\}$ uniformly distributed over $[0,B]$.
Then take the sample of the pairs: $\{(\vec X_n, Y_n)\}$.

Accept $\vec X_n$ if $$f(\vec X_n)\leq B_n$$
reject it otherwise. The distribution of the accepted samples will be of $f$.

Comment: Practical for small dimensions $n$. (+1) But for large $n$ the proportion of 'accepted' points will be very small compared to 'rejected' ones. [For example, the standard multivariate normal probability of the unit ball in 10-D is computed in R as `pchisq(1,10)` which returns 0.0001721156.]
In higher dimensions, maybe better to use an MCMC method such as a constrained random walk.