# What p.d.f. over angles is equivalent to a uniform distribution over a hypersphere?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, statistics

Eric Weisstein's [Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) points out that sampling uniformly from each angle $\phi$ and $\theta$ in spherical coordinates does **not** sample from the uniform sphere because it clusters near the poles. I am interested in which distribution over the angles **does** sample uniformly over the area element.

For the spherical case, he notes that the random variables $\phi$ and $\theta$ that do correspond to sampling from the uniform sphere are:

$\theta = 2\pi u \\
\phi = \cos^{-1}(2v -1)$

where $u$ and $v$ are random variables uniformly distributed over [0, 1].

I would like to know how this extends to n-dimensional hyperspheres. Is there a similar expression for the distribution of the angles $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ when sampling from a uniform hypersphere?

Very grateful for any help!

(I'm aware that there are simpler ways to sample from the unit hypersphere such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability/87238#87238). I'm specifically interested in the probability density function of the angles.)

Comment: It is not clear to me what  your "angles" are for $S^n$ for $n>2$.  Can you be more specific, relating your angles to some other standard parameterization, say that by $(x_1,\ldots x_n): \sum x_i^2=1$?

Comment: @kimchilover - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: @mr_e_man Oh, in that case don't the absolute values of the sines of the angles have Beta distributions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using hyperspherical coordinates, the area element of the $n$-sphere can be written $$ \sin^{n-1}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-2}(\phi_2)\ldots \sin(\phi_{n-1})d\phi_1\ldots d\phi_n$$ where $\phi_1,\ldots\phi_{n-1}$ range from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi_n$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi.$

So this gives you the pdf's of the angles right there: $\phi_n$ is uniform, $\phi_{n-1}$ has a pdf proportional to $\sin(\phi_{n-1}),$ etc.

I don't see a particularly nice way to express the inverse CDF though, which is what you need to get the expression in terms of a uniform. For instance, the way it works for $\phi_{n-1}$ is that $$ F(\phi_{n-1}) = \frac{\int_0^{\phi_{n-1}}\sin(\phi_{n-1})d\phi_{n-1}}{\int_0^\pi \sin(\phi_{n-1})d\phi_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(\phi_{n-1}))$$ which has inverse function $$F^{-1}(u) = \arccos(1-2u) $$ which agrees with what you were told for the polar angle in the three dimensional case.

But for $\phi_{n-2}$ we have $$ F(\phi_{n-2}) = \frac{\int_0^{\phi_{n-2}}\sin^2(\phi_{n-2})d\phi_{n-2}}{\int_0^\pi \sin(\phi_{n-2})d\phi_{n-2}} = \frac{1}{\pi}(\phi_{n-2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\phi_{n-2}))$$ which doesn't have any nice inverse in closed form I'm aware of. That said, the CDFs all have closed forms an it is easy enough to invert them numerically.

Comment: Thank you! I think this was exactly what I needed. I'll see if I can get this to work for me!