# How do I normalize a vector such that the sum of its squared elements is some arbitrary c?

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, random

I am trying to generate points (vectors) from the $L^2$ unit norm hypersphere uniformly at random.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577803/generating-random-vectors-of-euclidean-norm-1-in-python) says to:

1. Generate a random Gaussian $d$-dimensional vector $v$.
2. Generate a random uniform number $u$ in $[0, 1]$.
3. **"Normalize the vector to norm $u^{1/d}$."**

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to do step (3). I believe that to normalize a vector to 1, one would compute $\frac{v}{norm(v)}$. I have considered computing $\frac{v}{u^{1/d}}$, but this doesn't make sense to me, since in the first case our divisor was $norm(v)$ despite the fact that the desired norm of 1 was not equal to $norm(v)$.

In [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability) referenced by the above, someone has commented a Matlab implementation of the solution, which suggests that I should compute: $\frac{v u^{1/d}}{norm(v)}$... but I don't understand the rationale for this.

Could someone confirm that the latter method is correct, and perhaps explain how so? Is there a general way to normalize a $d$-dimensional vector so that its $L^p$ norm is $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is the strategy for random points in a unit ball, not for random points on a unit sphere.

Let us assume you have generated $v$ as a Gaussian $d$-dimensional vector. Normalizing this to length $1$ is done by using $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ as you correctly stated. This results in a uniform distribution on the surface of the unit sphere, as described in the article about [hypersphere point picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html).

In order to get points inside of the ball, you have to use another random variable to specify the distance from the origin. If you simply used a uniform distribution for this, you would get too many points near the origin and not enough points near the surface.

But if you take a variable $u$ with a uniform distribution and raise it to the $\frac{1}{d}$-th power, the resulting distribution ensures that the distribution of points inside the ball is uniform. In a manner of speaking, applying the $\frac{1}{d}$-th power moves the points outwards by just the correct amount to get a uniform distrubution in the ball.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a really clear conceptual explanation. Although you didn't explicitly say so, based on what you've said, I believe your programmatic recommendation/endorsement is to do as the Matlab recommended, i.e. normalise the vector then multiply it by u^{1/d}. I hope you'll correct me if this wasn't your point.

Comment: @derek1984 Yes, my point was to confirm the Matlab implementation mentioned in your question.