# Is there a way to derive the surface of a ball without integral?

Tags: geometry, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Surface Area of a Sphere be found without using Integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73348/can-the-surface-area-of-a-sphere-be-found-without-using-integration)

A ball is effectively a pyramid with "curved" based. If we know the surface, which is $O=4 \pi r^2$, we know the volume, which is $V=\frac{1}{3}  \cdot A \cdot  r = \frac43 \pi r^3$

I know I can derive the surface of the ball with calculus. Is there another way?

Comment: Some geometrical approach is given in robjohn's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164/why-is-the-volume-of-a-sphere-frac43-pi-r3/194953#194953).

Comment: It depends on what you call calculus.  Archimedes showed it was the same as the curved surface area of the surrounding cylinder so $2\pi rh = 4 \pi r^2$.

Comment: Similar question: [Can the Surface Area of a Sphere be found without using Integration?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73348/752).