# Volume of the part of the sphere that stays outside a cuboid.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

`Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Cuboid[{-(Sqrt[2]/2), -(Sqrt[2]/2), -(Sqrt[2]/2)}, {Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[2]/2}]}, Boxed -> False]`
[image]

How to calculate the volume of one of these sphere cuts? (what remains outside the cuboid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you just have to plug the values in the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap):

$$V=\frac{\pi h^2(3R-h)}3$$

In your case $R=1$ and $h=1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$.

---

Let me add one of the possible derivations of this formula. (I am aware this is not what the question is asking, but it might be interesting anyway.)

As I am not a native English speaker and I was never taught geometry in English, it is possible that in some places my terminology might be unusual. I'll be grateful, if more knowledgeable users correct me.

**Volume of spherical cap using [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle):**

We want to compare the volume of hemisphere (of radius $R$) and 
part of the cylinder outside the cone
(both cylinder and cone have height and radius of the base equal to 
$R$).

See the following picture or a nicer picture at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sphere_cavalieri.svg) from the article on Cavalieri's principle.

[image: dr2]

Note that area of the cut in the height $y$ is in both cases the same:

For the sphere, we get in the height $y$ a circle of radius
$\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$, hence the area equals $\pi(R^2-y^2)$.

In the other body (difference of cylinder and cone) the cut at the height $y$ is the area between two circles with radii
$R$ and $y$, hence the area is $\pi(R^2-y^2)$,
which is the same as for sphere. (See the following picture.)

[image: dr3]

Hence: volume of the hemisphere = volume of the cylinder - volume of the cone:
$$V_{1/2\text{sphere}}=V_{\text{cyl}}-V_{\text{cone}}$$

$$V=\pi R^3 - \frac 13 \pi R^3 = \frac23 \pi R^3$$

Volume of the spherical cap is the volume of the cyliner minus volume of the
truncated cone.

The cylinder has base with diameter  $R$ and height $h$: $$V_1=\pi R^2h.$$

The radii of lower and upper base of the truncated cone are  $R$ and $R-h$,
thus the volume is the difference between the volume of the whole cone and the truncated part:
$$V_2 = \frac 13 \pi R^3 -\frac 13 \pi (R-h)^3.$$

$$V=V_1-V_2 =
\pi R^2h - \left(\frac 13 \pi R^3 -\frac 13 \pi (R-h)^3\right) =$$
$$\pi R^2h - \frac{3\pi R^2h-3\pi Rh^2+\pi h^3}3 =$$
$$\frac{\pi h^2(3R-h)}3
$$

---

Volume of sphere is derived using Cavalieri's principle in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/181), too.