# Spatial Geometry - Hole in Sphere

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given a solid sphere of radius R, remove a cylinder whose central axis goes through the center of the sphere.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109908/given-a-solid-sphere-of-radius-r-remove-a-cylinder-whose-central-axis-goes-thro)

In a solid sphere I did a diametral hole with a cylindrical drill. I know that the distance between the two  border holes formed is 6cm. How can I calculate the remainder volume in the sphere?

[image]

Comment: That's a solid of revolution, so you could use the usual integration methods.

Comment: I think you're out of luck unless you know the radius of the sphere and/or of the cylinder.

Comment: @rschwieb: No, that's a "well"-known puzzle. The volume does not depend on the radius of the sphere.

Comment: My teacher said that is not necessary use calculus, and you don't need any radius.

Comment: If you know the radius is not important, just imagine a sphere of diameter $6$cm. Then the removed cylinder has negligible volume, so the object must have volume $(4/3)27\pi = 36\pi$.

Comment: That's correct! 36 pi is the answer. But I didn't understand.

Comment: @ypercube That's interesting. Unfortunately it is not well-known enough to have crossed my radar before now :)

Comment: I Understood =D