# Volume of solids - hollow cylinder

Tags: calculus

I know the title is somewhat vague, and for that I apologize.

I am currently stuck on the following problem
[image]

A solid is made from a sphere with some radius $R$ by first revolving some cylinder with a radius $b$ with its central axis in the center of the sphere. Adjacent to the cylinder axis a hole with radius $a$ is made. This results in some pipe-like solid with walls of thickness $b-a$ where the end is part of the sphere-surface.

Find the volume expressed with $a$, $b$ and $R$.

I've tried using integration on several different objects, but I can't seem to find the expression for the right one, i.e. I am integrating the wrong objects.

I don't need a conclusive answer, but if someone could give me a hint or a push in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it, because I am very much so stuck.

Comment: Think about revolving a portion of the disk around the vertical axis.  The shell method should work.

Comment: There is a classic problem of finding the volume of a [sphere with a hole drilled through it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227803/spatial-geometry-hole-in-sphere). Your case is the difference between two instances of that.