# How to prove volume and surface area of sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the volume of a sphere $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164/why-is-the-volume-of-a-sphere-frac43-pi-r3)

We know that the surface area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$ and the volume is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

How does one prove these formulae?

Comment: ... and see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625/why-is-the-derivative-of-a-circles-area-its-perimeter-and-similarly-for-sphere?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

For the area, use the equation of a circle of radius $r$, $x^2+y^2=r^2$, to find the area between two curves.

For the volume, view the sphere of radius $r$ as a solid of revolution of the function $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194953) I give a geometric derivation for the surface area of a sphere, then integrate that by shells to get the volume of the sphere.