# Area of a sphere

Tags: general-topology, geometry, soft-question

I want to know if the following GIF is **accurate or not**.

I saw that we **cannot** flatten a sphere without a *deformation* (world map problem).

And the GIF is actually "rolling" the sphere on a plane, projecting it so **does** this **implies** that the GIF is just here to help understand or is it false ?

*I know that we could integrate to calculate the area but I wanted to know if this GIF was accurate !*

**Here is the GIF :**
https://m.imgur.com/gallery/5RE0Twe

Comment: i thought u just integrate using surface area of solid of revolution on a semicircle

Comment: Ok thanks ! So the gif isn't 100% correct ?

Comment: The sphere inherits a Riemannian metric from $\mathbb{R}^3$ which then induces a volume form which can be integrated over the sphere.

Comment: The gif is flattening the sphere over a plane and it can't be done so it's not 100% correct !

Comment: What does this question have to do with topology? Area is not a topological property.

Comment: " Topology studies the properties of space that are preserved under continuous deformations, this means streching and bending ". Well, I want to know is this space propriety called area is kept under the deformation :) Try to answer the topic and try not to contest a specific tag, that's useless.

Comment: Agreed, splitting hairs over tags is rather useless. However for future reference, cutting the sphere in half isn't a continuous transformation, so it isn't really in the domain of topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering in a more calculus-oriented way, because it's obvious that's what OP is asking for.

It is true that you can't flatten a sphere onto a flat plane with a *finite collection* of pieces, but there's nothing stopping you from using an infinite number of pieces. The first part of the gif, before connecting all the little pieces, you're correct in that not being completely accurate. However, after cutting the sphere an infinite number of times, that geometric trick *can* be done.

The real issue with the gif, however, is that it gives no intuition as to why the area is related to sine, instead of some other wave-like curve. If it helps you remember, well the by all means use that animation as you see fit. However, if you want a deeper explanation, these gifs won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Topology concerns about continuous maps, as you said the continuous map can make the figure change, so does it's area. For example, the map 
$$f(x)=2x$$
maps an interval $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$. "The area" of $[0,1]$ is 1 and "the area" of $[0,2]$ is 2. So continuous maps do change the area. I hope this expression can convince you facts from topology of a figure tell nothing about its area.

Then if you want to know how to compute the area of a figure, for example sphere, then I suggest you take a look at a course in analysis and integral to see how. Or easier, here
[how to find surface area of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335577/how-to-find-surface-area-of-a-sphere)