# Area of flat surface = Half the surface area of hemisphere.

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Consider a sphere. Cut it in such a way that it results in two hemispheres. 
My question is why the surface area of the hemisphere is twice the area of the flat surface area?

By looking at the formulas one can conclude the above fact($2$x$\pi r^2$=$2\pi r^2$), but is there any intuitive way that can explain this?

Comment: you can watch youtube videos for this...best explained...

Comment: Can you point me to the video?

Comment: Probably of interest: [Deriving the formula of the Surface area of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417598). If that doesn't help, it would be helpful to explain exactly what you mean by a "logical way to explain this", and/or why calculating the two areas doesn't qualify. ;)

Comment: I must apologise for the wrong choice of words. Probably intuitive would have been the correct word. I will edit the question

Comment: Is robjohn's answer not intuitive in the sense you're asking...?