# Area of north cap of a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, surfaces, spheres

### Problem

Derive formula for area of cap of sphere where $h$ is height of the cap. Derive formula $A=2\pi Rh$.

Hint: (by rotating function $f(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ in between $R-h\le x\le R$)

### Attempt to solve

Now area of revolving function should be:

$$ A=2\pi \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx $$

I've tried to find where this formula comes from but i wasn't able to find proof for this. Now if someone knows how to prove this is valid formula / or if it isn't that would be great. (Possibly the cause of confusion on this problem).

We have the function given by the hint:

$$ f(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2} $$
$$ f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{R^2-x^2})=-\frac{-x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}  $$

Now to find out area this would be simply inserting function into the formula ?

$$ A=2\pi \int_{R-h}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\sqrt{1+(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}})^2}dx=2\pi Rh $$

I have tried to calculate the indefinite integral

$$ A=2\pi \int\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\sqrt{1+(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}})^2}dx=2\pi Rh $$
$$ A=2\pi(\frac{1}{4}(2x+1)\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\sqrt{\frac{-R^2+x^2+x}{x^2-R}}-\frac{1}{8}(4R^2+1)\tan^{-1}(\frac{(2x+1\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\sqrt{\frac{-R^2+x^2+x}{x^2-R^2}})}{2(-R^2+x^2+x)})) +c$$
I've tried to integrate this but with little success. However this is suppose to be same as $2\pi Rh$ (hence the equality at the end) but i don't have definite proof of it.

You can notice that $2\pi$ is only constant and does not come from the integration itself. So integration of something will most likely produce $Rh$

$$ \int_{R-h}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\sqrt{1+(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}})^2}dx=Rh $$

---

### To sum up the (possible) problems

**(a)** is formula for area correct in this. If it is where does it come from ?

**(b)** If we assume formula is correct then there has to be problem with my integration.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2474288/347062) is very similar conceptually.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1417631) derives the formula $2\pi rh$ geometrically.

Comment: Is $2\pi Rh$ not the formula for the surface area of a section of cylinder of height $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the formula is correct. You can find the derivation of the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula).

Second, you made some mistakes in simplifying the expressions. In particular,
$$f'(x) = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \implies \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} = \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}.$$
Consequently,
$$A = 2\pi \int_{R-h}^{R}|f(x)|\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx = 2\pi\int_{R-h}^{R}R\,dx=2\pi Rh.$$