# Trying to calculate how much the Space Station can see of Earth analytically

Tags: calculus, circles

I'm trying to calculate how much the Space Station can see of the Earth from upthere using functions and calculus.

Here's the information needed:

Earth's radius: $r = 6400$

ISS altitude from Earth's surface: $a = 400$

$b = a + r$

I've plotted the upper surface of the Earth:
$ y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$

The horizon lines would be tangential to the Earth, therefore the slope would be equal to the derivative of Earth's surface.

$y = mx + b$, where  $m = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{(r^2-x^2)}}$

combining both equations, I get that

$x = c = ±\frac{\sqrt{(r^2(a^2-r^2))}}{a}$

Then, using an integral, I calculated the arc length.

$s = \int_{0}^{c}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}})^2}}\text{ d}x$

$s = r  \text{ arcsin(}c/r)$

Using $ r \theta = s$, we can get $\theta = \text{ arcsin(}c/r) $

and to find the percentage, I divided by $2 \pi$, which gives about 5%

The supposed answer is ~4%, so are there any error in my solution or is this just a problem from assuming stuff?

Comment: It looks like you computed portion of great circle. See this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474288/visible-portion-of-the-earths-surface?rq=1